# How to permanently remove the taskbar from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

Is there a way to permanently remove the taskbar in Windows 7?

If so, what are the steps to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of Explorer.
Install either Litestep or Blackbox for Windows (http://bblean.sf.net)

Screenshot from boxshots.org
[image]

Comment: Sweet!  I did not realize you could use blackbox for windows!

Comment: If I actually used Windows, I would totally try blackbox in Windows.

Comment: @gabriel1836 my windows sshot http://oi56.tinypic.com/14wby9y.jpg ; btw, on linux/bsd you can use openbox/fluxbox, but there is no so good panel (built with bbslit+bbleanbar, using separate bbiconbox for quicklaunch and possible to use to show window icons too)

Answer (score 5):

From The Windows Club:  A small app called "Taskbar Eliminator", you can toggle the taskbar off and on...

> http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-hide-or-remove-windows-7-taskbar

From MakeUseOf: 3 Ways to Remove the Windows Vista (also applies to Win7) taskbar:

> http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-ways-to-get-rid-of-the-vista-task-bar/

Comment: Have misread as: "3 Ways to Remove the Windows Vista (also applies to taskbar)"

Comment: @mhambra: what do you mean? I am confused?

Comment: Err.. the title of last link looks like "Remove windows - and never see that task bar".